# How to reset ComboBox and display PromptText?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

**Note:** *I am expanding on duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567738/reset-the-combobox-in-javafx) because it does not include a MCVE. The few other similar questions I've found also do not include working answers.*

I am unable to find a way to have a `ComboBox` display the `PromptText` after clearing the selection.

Here is the MCVE:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        final VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        final ComboBox<String> cboSelection = new ComboBox<>();
        final Button btnClear = new Button("Clear");

        // Set ComboBox selections
        final ObservableList<String> subjectsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        subjectsList.addAll("Software", "Math", "Physics");

        // Setup the Subject selection
        cboSelection.setPromptText("Select Subject");
        cboSelection.setItems(subjectsList);

        // Set action for "Clear" button
        btnClear.setOnAction(e -> {
            cboSelection.setValue(null);
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(cboSelection, btnClear);

        primaryStage.setTitle("ComboBox Demo");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 100));
        primaryStage.show();


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Clicking the "Clear" button will set the selected value to `null` and clear the selection of the `ComboBox`, but the prompt text does not show again. This does not seem like the normal expected behavior.

I have tried `clearSelection()` as well as `setPromptText()` within the button's `onAction` and nothing seems to work to get the prompt text back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#promptTextProperty), the prompt text should not actually be displayed at all here:

> Prompt text is not displayed in all circumstances, it is dependent upon the subclasses of ComboBoxBase to clarify when promptText will be shown. For example, in most cases prompt text will never be shown when a combo box is non-editable (that is, prompt text is only shown when user input is allowed via text input).

If you want to see some prompt text when the selection is null (and you do not have an editable combo box), use a custom `buttonCell` on the combo box:

```
    cboSelection.setPromptText("Select Subject");
    cboSelection.setButtonCell(new ListCell<String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText("Select Subject");
            } else {
                setText(item);
            }
        }
    });
```

Note that it seems you *also* need to set the prompt text, as in the code in the question, in order to get the text to appear initially. I assume this is because of the same bug (I'm guessing that the library code is incorrectly setting the text of the button cell to the prompt text initially; if the prompt text is not set, the text gets set to `null`, apparently *after* the button cell's update method is invoked).

And you can obviously make this reusable by creating a named subclass of `ListCell`:

```
public class PromptButtonCell<T> extends ListCell<T> {

    private final StringProperty promptText = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public PromptButtonCell(String promptText) {
        this.promptText.addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
            if (isEmpty() || getItem() == null) {
                setText(newText);
            }
        });
        setPromptText(promptText);
    }

    public StringProperty promptTextProperty() {
        return promptText ;
    }

    public final String getPromptText() {
        return promptTextProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setPromptText(String promptText) {
        promptTextProperty().set(promptText);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(getPromptText());
        } else {
            setText(item);
        }
    }
}
```

and then just

```
cboSelection.setButtonCell("Select Subject");
cboSelection.setButtonCell(new PromptButtonCell<>("Select Subject"));
```

Comment: Where does the first value of `empty` come from in the constructor of the subclass? The sample class will not compile. Also FYI, when adding the listener, you're missing the `this` keyword for the `promptText` reference.

Comment: Incidentally, I changed the constructor of your sample class to only setting the `promptText`, omitting the listener, and the functionality of the ComboBox works as expected.

Comment: @Zephyr Sorry, should have been the method call; see update. (I tested the first version, but not the reusable one.) `this` is optional. The listener is only needed in case you change the prompt text later, while the selection is null.

Comment: Ah, that's better. Though I still believe `this` is required since you have `promptText` as the name of the string passed to the constructor as well. That being said, this answer works well for the issue at hand and I was not aware of what the docs said about the prompt text on un-editable ComboBoxes, so thank you for that.